# Python-Pygame sprite bounces when gravity is used

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, sprite, gravity

I am making a 8bit style platformer. The player falls and gains speed because of the pseudo gravity but he will fall a few pixels into the ground level. Without gravity he will land on the ground and not fall though but it is a constant fall speed.When in the ground you can go up but he will fall when you let up. He will not got down so that is not an issue for now. Any help would be appreciated.

The player class/file.

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
class Player:
    x=0
    y=0
    offset = 5
    L=False
    R=False
    U=False
    D=False
    image = None
    gravity = .25
    velocity = offset
    objectDict = None #this si the list of the current objects so that collision can be check with every
    #object.. get updated every loop to keep a accurate check of locations
    rect = None
    grav = True    #TODO use this to check if we are paying attention to the gravity
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Resources/Pics/player.png')



    def draw(self,DISPLAY):
        #print('draw will go here')
        imgRect = self.image.get_rect()
        imgRect.midleft = (self.x,self.y)
        self.rect = imgRect
        DISPLAY.blit(self.image, imgRect)
        #and now im here

    def checkCollide(self,otherRect):
        return self.rect.colliderect(otherRect)

    def checkCollideAll(self):
        if(self.objectDict != None):
            # print(len(self.objectDict))
        #     for x in range(1,len(self.objectDict)):
        #         newb = self.checkCollide(self.objectDict[x].getRect())
        #         print(self.objectDict[x].getRect())
        #     if(newb):
        #         return True
        # return False
            collideNum = self.rect.collidelist(self.objectDict)
            if(collideNum == -1):
                return False
            else:
                return True

    def willCollideBelow(self):
        if(self.objectDict):
            checkRect = (self.x,(self.y),self.image.get_size())
            collideNum = self.rect.collidelist(self.objectDict)
            if collideNum == -1:
                return False
            else:
                return True


    def objUpdate(self,dict):
        self.objectDict = dict

    def getRect(self):
        return self.rect

    def update(self):
        # while(self.checkCollideAll()):
        #     print('while happened')
        #     self.y -= self.offset
        #     imgRect = self.image.get_rect()
        #     imgRect.midleft = (self.x,self.y)
        #     self.rect = imgRect
        # print(self.willCollideBelow())
        if not self.willCollideBelow():
            self.D = True
            # print('will fall')
        else:
            self.D = False

        if self.U == True:
            self.y -= self.offset

        if self.D == True:
                self.y += self.velocity
                if not self.velocity >= 9.8:
                    self.velocity += self.gravity
        else:
            self.velocity = self.offset
        if self.L == True:
                self.x -= self.offset

        if self.R == True:
                self.x += self.offset
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that your character is falling such that he intersects the ground?  If that's the case then it's because in one timestep he falls a greater distance than he was above the ground, and it doesn't look like you have any code to resolve that intersection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide a running example and your code is hard to read (pascal case, a lot of unnecessary parenthesis), but here's my guess:

In your `willCollideBelow` function, you check if you hit an object beneath the player:

```
def willCollideBelow(self):
        if(self.objectDict):
            checkRect = (self.x,(self.y),self.image.get_size())
            collideNum = self.rect.collidelist(self.objectDict)
            if collideNum == -1:
                return False
            else:
                return True
```

instead of just returning `True` or `False`, return the object (or the index of the object) you actually collide with:

```
def will_collide_below(self):
        if(self.objectDict):
            # using 'collidelistall' would be better, but that's another topic
            return self.rect.collidelist(self.objectDict)
```

Now that you know which object the player collides with, you can adjust the vertical position of the player:

```
ground_i = self.will_collide_below()
if ground_i:
    ground = self.objectDict[ground_i]
    self.velocity = 0
    self.rect.bottom = ground.top # or self.y = ground.top
```

You'll get the idea.

---

Some more notes:

You use different variables to store the position of the player (I see `x`, `y`, `rect` and `imgRect`). It would make you code a lot simpler if you would just use a single `Rect` to store the position:

```
class Player:
    ...
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.image = pygame.image.load('Resources/Pics/player.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(midleft=(x,y))

    def draw(self, display):
        display.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        ...
        if self.L: # no need to check == True
            self.rect.move_ip(-self.offset)

        if self.R: # simply use move_ip to alter the position
            self.rect.move_ip(self.offset)
```

You also use a bunch of class variables where you really should use instance variables, like `rect`, `L`, `R`, `U` and `D`.

Comment: Thank you that makes much more sense. Also the camelcase and parenthesis are because we have experience in VB and Java which thoroughly ruin all logical formatting when it comes to moving to Python.